# Benefits of using QOpenGLWidget over normal QWidget

Tags: qt, opengl

Since Qt 5.4 version, the QOpenGLWidget was introduced to enable the OpenGL rendering capabilities.

Apart of calling OpenGL APIs, QOpenGLWidget can also be used as a normal QWidget, in which QPainter is used.

So I'm wondering, if I don't plan to directly call any OpenGL API to render my widget, but only QPainter APIs, is there still any (performance perhaps) benefits of using QOpenGLWidget instead of QWidget?

Comment: It may have benefits (I haven't seen yet high performance using a "casual" QPainter and used `QGLWidget` with OpenGL API; but who knows?). But when you mess with platform+hardware+driver specific things you should think twice. Because your widget may appear differently on each machine, it may be faster or slower, old machines with old drivers may reject new OpenGL features, OpenGL may require additional settings for network display, etc.

Comment: So there is actually no enough motivation to use the QOpenGLWidget, unless intensive OpenGL calls are required, right?

Comment: The purpose of `QOpenGLWidget` is to have a rectangular area inside your window to render OpenGL scene on. `QOpenGLWidget` brings only an overhead, because it needs to be a specific resource with a window ID, so the 3D driver and OS can use it directly.

Comment: @Wayee I don't see the motivation. Maybe someone does, don't know. But for me @Velkan is right, basically `QOpenGLWidget` is a window to use and display OpenGL scenes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QOpenGLWidget`, when directly painted on using `QPainter`, does all the painting using OpenGL - that's one of its two main purposes. Using `QPainter` on a `QOpenGLWidget` has Qt doing the legwork of translating the painter API into GL state setup and draw calls. If you have some OpenGL background and use a debug build of Qt, you can trace into the source and see how Qt translates your calls, so that you can issue your painter calls in a way that efficiently maps to OpenGL. State changes are expensive, so make sure you batch the operations that use the same pen/brush etc. The painting is done by the `QOpenGL2PaintEngineEx`.